Masturbation Help
Assalamwalaikum
I am  15 almost 16 year old male. I have a question that I hope is answered. I have started to become a more religious teenager at the start of this year but masturbation is my problem. In my opinion I have a serious addiction because I have the urge to do it every night. I have broken 3 of my fasts this Ramadan because of masturbation. I have heard that it is a sin. I would like to come out of this addiction. If there is anyone that knows how to help me it is much appreciated.

Salam Rayan,
It's a serious problem. Many teenagers I know have also this problem. It will impact their sexual and married future. You can watch this video for SQ How I overcome my masturbation addiction
